Characterisations of functors $F$ such that $F^*$ or $F_*$ is [property], e.g. faithful, conservative, etc
I'm currently writing a comprehensive/encyclopedic set of notes on category theory (EDIT: now up here), and one of the things I'm trying to do is gather all sorts of statements of the form

Let $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor. The following conditions are equivalent:

For each $X\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathsf{Cats})$, the precomposition functor
$$F^* \colon \mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{X}) \to \mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{X})$$
is X for X some nice property (e.g. conservative).
[Other conditions on $F$ itself]


or with postcomposition
$$F_*\colon\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{C})\to\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{D})$$
replacing $F^*$.
So far, I've found characterisations for some nice properties, but there are many, many ones I still haven't found anything about.
Thus, I thought it might be a good idea to collect those into a single question here on MO, to keep track of all those:
Known characterisations:


$F_*$ is full/faithful/fully faithful.
$F^*$ is full/faithful/fully faithful (though see also MO 468121).
$F^*$ is conservative.


(See Clowder, Tags 0116, 011R, and 0128.)
Characterisations which I haven't yet found a reference for or worked out:


$F_*$ is conservative.
$F_*$ is essentially injective, i.e. $F\circ\phi\cong F\circ\psi$ implies $\phi\cong\psi$.
$F^*$ is essentially injective, i.e. $\phi\circ F\cong\psi\circ F$ implies $\phi\cong\psi$.
$F_*$ (resp. $F^*$) is essentially surjective.
$F_*$ (resp. $F^*$) is a monomorphism (resp. an epimorphism).
$F_*$ (resp. $F^*$) is pseudomonic (resp. pseudoepic).
$F_*$ (resp. $F^*$) is dominant.


I'm also interested on the following two natural refinements of Items 2 and 3 above:


The functor
$$F_*\colon\mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{C}))\to\mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{D}))$$
is full, i.e. if $F\circ\phi\cong F\circ\psi$ via a natural isomorphism $\beta$, then $\phi\cong\psi$ via a natural isomorphism $\alpha$ and we have $\beta=\mathrm{id}_{F}\star\alpha$.
The functor
$$F^*\colon\mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{X}))\to\mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{X}))$$
is full, i.e. if $\phi\circ F\cong \psi\circ F$ via $\beta$, then $\phi\cong\psi$ via $\alpha$ and $\beta=\alpha\star\mathrm{id}_{F}$.


A few of these seem hard enough that probably no answer is currently known (or way too hard, like epimorphisms), but I suspect some of these are things that have been worked out already somewhere or are possibly folklore among the correct experts, but so far I haven't had much luck procuring references or statements for them.

I would be interested in a reference for when $F^*$ is fully faithful.

See https://www.clowderproject.com/tag/0128.html

@ManuelAraújo Hi Manuel! I've now updated the question with references for the "known characterisations". I wanted to push an update to Clowder correcting a mistake pointed out by Naïm before updating the question (hence the delay).

Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100808/properties-of-functors-and-their-adjoints?rq=1

Emily and @NaïmFavier thanks!
